# Запустить функцию после отработки предыдущей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, есть функция которая рендерит пользователей, после рендера мне нужно сделать "active" определенного пользователя из нового списка. Проблема в том что не понимаю как отследить окончание рендера пользователей, чтобы потом запустить функцию которая добавляет класс "Active", сейчас эта функция просто содержится внутри ф-ции рендера и запускается через setTimeout, это работает но коряво. 
Схематично

```
function renderContacts(data){
    some code //создание пользователей
    if($('.people .person').hasClass('active') === false)
        setTimeout(function(){$('.people .person:first-child').click()},5)
    //Если я не определил нужно пользователя, то выбираю просто первого
    return $('.people').html(r); // а вот здесь рендерятся уже пользователи, если выше
    //я не буду выделять пользователей через Timeout, то никто не получит класс "Active"
   //т.к. на момент работы ф-ции пользователи ещё не отрендерены и искать в DOM нечего
}
```

Как-то можно вынести отдельно ф-цию которая делает нужного пользователя "Active" и при это привязать её к окончанию выполнения Рендера?) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise` в помощь:

```
function render() {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        setTimeout( ()=> {
            console.log( 'Пользователи отрендерены' );
            resolve( 'рузультирующее значение, которое передано дальше' );
        }, 3000 );
    } )
}

render().then( ( resMessage ) => {
    console.log( resMessage );
    console.log('делаю его активным' );
} );
```

Т.е. возвращаем из функции render `Promise`. Я взял для примера что он что-то делает в течение 3 секунд, после 3 секунд выводит "пользователи отрендерены". С помощью `resolve` можно дальше передать какое-нибудь значение, а можно и не передавать и просто вызвать `resolve()`. Вызываю функцию `render()` и по завершении будет вызвана функция внутри `then`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderContacts(data){
    some code //создание пользователей и получение их кол-ва
    while($('.people .person').length<кол-во пользователей){}//тем временем остальной код выполняться не будет...
    if($('.people .person').hasClass('active') === false)
            $('.people .person:first-child').click();
    return $('.people').html(r);
}
```